# retrieve Datetime object from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a specific problem regarding the mysql Datetime format to store the date and time together in table, so I have stored values in the table and now I want to retrieve those values and then compare that time with current datetime but things are going horribly wrong.
this is what i tried so far..

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    require_once('connect.php');

    $query="select matchTime from fixture_list where value1='Mumbai'";
    if($result= mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            print_r($row);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    //$target = new DateTime('2018-07-27 01:00:00');
    $target = new DateTime($query);
    $now = new DateTime;
    $diff = $target->diff($now);

    if ($target > $now) {
        echo $diff->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes to go');
    } 
    else {
        echo $diff->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes too late');
    }
?>
```

My only purpose is to get the datetime value in string propbably which has been stored in the database and pass it to $target variable and then compare with $now, this is the error I m getting "Array ( [matchTime] => 2018-07-27 00:00:00 ) Array ( [matchTime] => 2018-07-27 00:00:00 ) Array ( [matchTime] => 2018-07-28 01:00:00 ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (select matchTime from fixture_list) at position 0 (s): The timezone could not be found in the database'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$target = new DateTime($query);
```

should be:

```
$target = new DateTime($row['matchTime']);
```

Comment: How to use where clause in matchTime inside row??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean table has multiple rows , but I want to retrieve Datetime of any perticular row at a time so I will have to apply some constrains like where clause

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing with `where value1='Mumbai'`? Or perhaps you want something like `where matchTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`?

Comment: Ya what I am doing with where value1='mumbai', will this work ??

Comment: If I write something like $target = new DateTime($row[&#39;matchTime where value1=mumbai&#39;]);
Will this be ok

Comment: What you are doing at the moment (`where value1='Mumbai'`) is correct. The call to DateTime is ONLY to convert a string value that has already been read from the database into a date, so that's not the place to put query conditions.

Comment: Ok thanks , let me check it and I will come back to you in sometime if any query occurs and mark the answer accepted shortly and thanks for the answer 

Comment: It did the trick, thanks man, I was stuck with this problem for 4 days and I got the answer in 4 hours after asking the question here, Just love the StackOverflow and The Internet